# What does "he is kind of big deal" mean?

Tags: expressions

What does *he is kind of big deal* mean?

In [this dictionary](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3Abig%20deal), it means *an important person*

In [another dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Big%20Deal), it means *A sarcastic way of referring to some one who has had an incredible run of good fortune.*

I am living in Australia, *big deal* also adds some sort of *arrogant* in it. So, *he is kind of big deal* also means *he thinks he is important person and allow himself to be arrogant*

Comment: [Picture worth a thousand words](http://www.quickmeme.com/img/5f/5fe03ddff8bc25ec63b2ae5db308290ee87ceeea1c6f1c1c4d0a035b1af7e66e.jpg)

Comment: It basically means he's important, but may be used sarcastically in several different ways.  The definitions you quote capture the range of meanings pretty well.

Comment: what does "incredible run of good fortune" mean?

Comment: Note: we normally say that someone is ***a*** big deal, with the article (and by ‘normally’, I mean that I have never in my life heard it without the article from any native English speaker). “Big deal” with no article is only used in [its other use](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Big+Deal&defid=5999473), as a sarcastic exclamation meaning “Yeah, so what? I don’t care”.

Answer (score 1):

As you indicate, *big deal* means *important person*. The phrase *[kind of](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/kind+of)* is a modifier that means

> to a moderate degree :  somewhat - *it's kind of late to begin*

*Merriam-Webster*

When coupled with a reference to something serious or important, it is a form of *understatement* or *[meiosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meiosis)*

> a euphemistic figure of speech that intentionally understates something or implies that it is lesser in significance or size than it really is.

*Wikipedia*

The speaker is suggesting that the person referred to really is important.